Multiple splide carousels- how can I store each carousel in a forLoop as a separate variable so I can use splide.go() to advance slides?
This may be more of a javascript question with .forEach loops but basically the loop makes a new splide carousel each time the module is used.
Tl;DR: if I have a .forEach loop how can I save each of the splide carousels as a variable? is it possible?
Before, I had a function that took a data-id to correspond to a specific image in the splide carousel and passed it through the splide.go(); function to advance the carousel to a specific image when clicking corresponding buttons.
Ever since making a .forEach loop this breaks (because I don't have a splide variable anymore like before). How can I make a variable for each carousel that I can then use to advance the slide how it should be?
The code will break because it has Hubl (Hubspot) code for the fields/data id info


$(document).ready(function() {
  var splide = new Splide('#features-image-carousel', {
    pagination: false,
    autoplay: false,
    arrows: true,
    navigation: false,
    type: 'loop',
    perPage: 1,
  }).mount();

  $('.features-top-tab .button-primary').click(function() {
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    splide.go(id - 1);
  });


  var button = document.querySelector('.features-image-carousel-container .features-top-tab .button-primary');
  button.classList.add('active');

  $(function() {

    $(".features-image-carousel-container .features-top-tab .button-primary").on("click", function(e) {
      $('.features-image-carousel-container .features-top-tab .button-primary').not(this).removeClass('active')
      $(this).addClass("active")
    })

  });
})
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="features-carousel">
  <section class="splide" id="features-image-carousel" aria-label="Splide Basic HTML Example">
    <div class="splide__arrows">
      <button class="splide__arrow splide__arrow--prev">
                         </button>
      <button class="splide__arrow splide__arrow--next">
                         </button>
    </div>

    <div class="splide__track">
      <ul class="splide__list">

        <li class="splide__slide">

          <img data-src="{{ item.src }}" src="{{ item.src|escape_url }}" alt="{{ item.alt|escape_attr }}" {{ loadingAttr }} {{ sizeAttrs }}> {% endif %}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="features-top-tab-row">
      {% for item in module.top_carousel_tab %}
      <div class="features-top-tab">
        <div data-id="{{loop.index}}" class="button-primary">
          {% inline_text field="top_carousel_tab_text" value="{{ item.top_carousel_tab_text }}" %}
        </div>
      </div>

      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </section>
</div>



My .forEach loop is here (where it broke because there is no variable to attach to the .go() function:
$(document).ready(function(){

    document.querySelectorAll('.splide').forEach(carousel => new Splide( carousel, {
 pagination: false,
    autoplay: false,
    arrows: true,
        navigation:false,
    type: 'loop',
    perPage: 1,
} ).mount());

Info on the splide.go() command is here: https://splidejs.com/components/controller/
